# Como organizar dados em 3 colunas sem quebra de layout, usando CSS Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, flexbox

Eu tenho uma lista de itens (ul), e cada item ocupa 33% da tela, formando assim uma lista horizontal de 3 colunas. Quando não há mais espaço na horizontal, ele forma uma nova linha, algo bem simples, fica perfeito quando todos os itens tem a mesma altura, mas quando as alturas são diferentes entre si, o layout "quebra". Segue a imagem e código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.news-line {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.news-line .news-line_title {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.news-line .news-line_title span {
  border-top: 2px solid #000;
}

.news-line .news-wrapper ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.news-line .news-wrapper ul li {
  margin: 0;
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
}

.news-line .news-wrapper ul li .box {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
}

.news-line .news-wrapper ul li .box .image {
  background: url('http://grafreez.com/wp-content/temp_demos/river/img/media-7.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 200px; 
}

.news-line .news-wrapper ul li .box .content {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
}

.news-line .news-wrapper ul li .box .content .date {
  margin-left: 30px;
  float: right;
}

.news-line .more-news {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.news-line .more-news a {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="news-line">
   <div class="news-line_title"><span>Últimas Notícias</span></div>

   <div class="news-wrapper">
    <ul>
     <li>
      <div class="box">
       <div class="image"></div>
       <div class="content">
        <span class="title">Syria War: Why the battle for Aleppo mattersSyria War: Why the battle for Aleppo matters?</span>
        <span class="date">2 hours ago</span>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>

     <li>
      <div class="box">
       <div class="image"></div>
       <div class="content">
        <span class="title">Syria War: Why the battle for Aleppo matters?</span>
        <span class="date">2 hours ago</span>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>

     <li>
      <div class="box">
       <div class="image"></div>
       <div class="content">
        <span class="title">Syria War: Why the battle for Aleppo matters?</span>
        <span class="date">2 hours ago</span>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>

     <li>
      <div class="box">
       <div class="image"></div>
       <div class="content">
        <span class="title">Syria War: Why the battle for Aleppo matters?</span>
        <span class="date">2 hours ago</span>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>

     <li>
      <div class="box">
       <div class="image"></div>
       <div class="content">
        <span class="title">Syria War: Why the battle for Aleppo matters?</span>
        <span class="date">2 hours ago</span>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>

     <li>
      <div class="box">
       <div class="image"></div>
       <div class="content">
        <span class="title">Syria War: Why the battle for Aleppo matters?</span>
        <br/>
        <span class="date">2 hours ago</span>
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>

   <div class="more-news"><a href="#">Ver todos</a></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você já está usando o `display: flex` use os atributos `flex-direction: row` e `flex-wrap: wrap`.

[Fonte](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)